# extract `.for()` into a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class like this one:

```
class House

   def bricks
      Brick.for(@house_plan).where(size: 5)
   end

   def wood
       Wood.for(@house_plan).where(size: 5)
   end
end
```

My goal is to **extract the call** `for(self).where(size: 5)`:

What I tried first was:

```
  class House

   def bricks
      Brick.match_material
   end

   def wood
       Wood.match_material
   end

   def match_material
       for(@house_plan).where(size: 5)
   end

end
```

**But then I got this error:**

```
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
```

**Then I changed my code to:**

```
   def match_material
       .for(@house_plan).where(size: 5)
   end
```

And now when I do:

```
 house = House.new(HousePlan.new)
 house.bricks
```

**I get this error:**

```
formal argument cannot be an instance variable
```

In this line:   `for(@house_plan).where(size: 5)`

### What do I wrong?

Comment: Isn't `for` a reserved keyword anw?

Comment: we badly need context, its it active record? what is `for`?

Comment: @PNY you can call a method `for`.

Comment: sure but in his examples he is calling `for` on `self` which has not defined such method

Comment: @PNY you're right - and that's direct cause of the first error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach isn't right, remember `match_material` method will always be called in the context of your self. I would do it this way:

```
def bricks
  match_material(Brick)
end

def wood
  match_material(Wood)
end

def match_material(klass)
  klass.for(@house_plan).where(size: 5)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
def bricks
  klazz = Kernel.const_get(__callee__[0...-1].capitalize)
  klazz.for(@house_plan).where(size: 5)
end
alias :woods :bricks
```

NB: In this approach aliased methods are to be named consistently(`bricks`, `woods`.) Please don’t use it in production unless you understand what you are doing.